# Visual Studio plugin for automating nunit test creation?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, plugins

You know how they say, "There's an app for that"? Well, is there a VS plugin for this ................. ?

I want to be able to right click on a method and select "Create unit test method ..." and have it generate an nunit stub in a particular place in my project tree. So for example. I have a `TheNextBigThing` library with an `Idea` class and a `MakeMeRich()` method. I want to have it, for example, create a unit test method in my `Tests` project in a sub-folder named `TheNextBigThing`, in a class named `IdeaTests`.

I know. I know. All the TDD advocates will tell me I'm doing it backward, but humor me. I have some code I want to retrofit with some tests, and I sometimes write methods before tests.

If it doesn't exist, any pointers on how to write it myself?

Comment: I thought all versions of 2010 had the unit testing functionality built in... is it that you're looking to customize where the tests are created?

Comment: Right. I need it for nunit not msunit or whatever it's called. I've made some edits to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Visual Studio 2010 Professional or Premium you have the option to create a unit test with MSTest by right clicking on the method.

Also, I would suggest using Pex.  Pex will create the unit test for you, in addition to all unit tests needed to achieve 100% code coverage of a particular method.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be too hard to get the addin started. Since you have VS already, simply create new project > VS Extensibility. :)

You'll most likey have to learn some codegen unless you utilize a templating language of some sort.

Me? I think it's a cool idea and I'd like to see it implemented. Start it up, share it on github (or similar) and watch it grow.